# Website redirecting to old domain name

Tags: redirect, wp-config, domain, dns

I was developing website on `test.example.com` on a separate server. Meanwhile, the working server was `example.com` at GoDaddy.

The WordPress website was working fine on both servers. But then I changed the registrar and decided to change the WordPress on `test.example.com` to `example.com` inside of the `wp-config.php`. If I'm entering `example.com/wp-admin` - it opens without problem. However, when I try `example.com` it redirects to `test.example.com`.

Can't figure out why it's happening.

Comment: If I understand your current scenario, you are no longer on two different servers? You only have

Comment: Right, I changed registrar and the old server is no more available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few variables that need to be changed in order for you to update to the new link on your WordPress site.

As mentioned by [Mark](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/268/markratledge), try the following steps using the Search Replace DB tool:

1. Go and download [Interconnect IT's Database Search & Replace Script here](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/archive/master.zip)
2. Unzip the file and drop the folder in your **localhost** where your WordPress is installed (the root) and rename the folder to **`replace`** ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Ga5.png))
3. Navigate to the new folder you created in your browser (ex: `http://example.com/replace`) and [you will see the search/replace tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbED1.png)
4. It should be pretty self-explanatory up to this point: enter your old URL in the **`search for…`** field and the new URL in the **`replace with…`** field

You can click the *dry run* button under *actions* to see what it will be replacing before you execute the script. Once you're done be sure to remove the `/replace/` folder.

Answer (score 3):

@maximus: It's not a good idea to run raw SQL queries on the database via phpmyadmin; direct queries will will break serialized data in the database, i.e. break widget data, theme options, etc. Use https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases to change domains, move from https to https, etc. It's a proven tool and is the answer to many other similar questions here on WpDev.